# How to short-circuit flattening in numpy.append

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data-structure that inherits from a third-party class which overloads `__getitem__`, returning a tuple.

Now, I have code elsewhere that involves appending a collection of these objects to a NumPy array:

```
class ThirdPartyThing:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return (self, key)

    def __iter__(self):
        return zip([self] * self.size, range(self.size))

class MyThing(ThirdPartyThing):
    pass

x = numpy.array([], dtype = MyThing, ndmin = 1)
temp = [MyThing(1) for _ in range(5)]
x = numpy.append(x, temp)
```

What I expected when I did this was a Numpy array with five objects of type `MyThing` but what I get is a 1-d array like this:

```
[MyThing(), 0, MyThing(), 0, MyThing(), 0, MyThing(), 0, MyThing(), 0]
```

which is of length 10 where every other-element is an integer.

According to [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), `append` attempts to flatten the array if `axis` is not defined but defining axis doesn't make a difference in my case. Is there anyway to avoid this pitfall?

**Update**
After closer inspection, I realized that the base class overloads `__len__`. I think that's what is causing the problem here.

Comment: Yes, don't use `np.append` at all.  If you must, look at its code first.

Comment: I get a 5 element object array with `MyThing`s.

Comment: `np.append` is a front end to `np.concatenate`, which is supposed to give a bit of the flavor of the list `append`.  But people misuse all the time.  It's much better to use `np.concatenate` directly.  And don't use that in a loop either.  Collect all values in a list, and make array with one call.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited the question to add more detail because your result and mine clearly differ

Comment: That's not an actual result.  Where's the `0` from.  `MyThing` doesn't have a `__str__` method, so it displays as `<__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f163774d6d8>`.

Comment: @hpaulj The actual class does, I simply omitted it to keep the example simple

Comment: @hpaulj My apologies. I suspected that the class's `__getitem__` definition was the problem because it's clearly poorly-written but the cause of the problem appears to be the class's `__iter__` definition instead

Comment: @Woody1193 You were right to create a mockup of the actual classed used. It seems, though, you took it a step too far and made it inconsistent with the output you get from the real thing. It does not create the 0s which seem to be the problem. Also, please specify how exactly you passed `axis` to `append`.

Comment: @kazemakase I'm not sure if you've seen my most recent update or not but I have been able to reproduce the issue with the code above. `axis` is an optional parameter in `append` so I passed it as such

Comment: @kazemakase You were correct. The mocked version I added here was missing a definition for `__len__`, which was contained in the actual code and which seems to be the actual source of this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact copy from your post:

```
In [1]: class MyThing: 
   ...:     pass 
   ...:  
   ...: x = numpy.array([], dtype = MyThing, ndmin = 1) 
   ...: temp = [MyThing() for _ in range(5)] 
   ...: x = numpy.append(x, temp)                                               
In [2]: x                                                                       
Out[2]: 
array([<__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21b45cd2e8>,
       <__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21b45cd278>,
       <__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21b45cd240>,
       <__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21b45cd320>,
       <__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21b45cd390>], dtype=object)
```

As for `np.append`, its code is:

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

So with an axis it is just `concatenate`.  Without  it makes sure both arguments are 1d.

Your `x` is (0,) shape, your `temp` is a 5 element list, which asarray becomes (5,) shape, with the result being (5,)

```
In [14]: x=numpy.array([], dtype = MyThing, ndmin = 1)                          
In [15]: x.shape                                                                
Out[15]: (0,)
In [16]: np.array(temp).shape                                                   
Out[16]: (5,)
In [17]: np.concatenate((x,temp)).shape                                         
Out[17]: (5,)
```

I don't see the issue.  The 'flattening' in `np.append` doesn't affect the code.  But as I commented, I don't like `np.append`. It confuses too many new users, and isn't needed.  Use `concatenate` directly.

You also include code for `ThirdPartyThing` class, but don't make any use of it.

---

Give `MyThing` a repr:

```
In [21]: MyThing.__repr__= lambda self: "MYTHING"
```

And define a different `temp`:

```
In [28]: temp1 = np.array([(MyThing(),0) for _ in range(3)])
```

Now we see the effect of the `append` ravels:

```
In [30]: np.append(x,temp1)                                                     
Out[30]: array([MYTHING, 0, MYTHING, 0, MYTHING, 0], dtype=object)
```

The (3,2) `temp1` becomes `(6m,)` before joining with (0,) `x`.

Adding `axis=0` doesn't work because different number of dimensions.

---

With your edited code:

```
In [64]: temp = np.array([MyThing(1) for _ in range(3)])                        
In [65]: temp                                                                   
Out[65]: 
array([[[<__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21adbc5048>, 0]],

       [[<__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21adbc5a58>, 0]],

       [[<__main__.MyThing object at 0x7f21adbc5470>, 0]]], dtype=object)

In [66]: temp.shape                                                             
Out[66]: (3, 1, 2)
```

or with my repr:

```
In [67]: MyThing.__repr__= lambda self: "MYTHING"                               
In [68]: temp                                                                   
Out[68]: 
array([[[MYTHING, 0]],

       [[MYTHING, 0]],

       [[MYTHING, 0]]], dtype=object)

In [70]: np.append(x,temp)                                                      
Out[70]: array([MYTHING, 0, MYTHING, 0, MYTHING, 0], dtype=object)
```

and adding `axis=0` still gives

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

However you construct it, trying to join a (0,) shape array with a (3,1,2) shape one requires some tweaking.

But why would one want to join those two arrays?  Where did the (0,) shape array come from in the first place?

---

The way you construct the list is the source of your problems:

```
In [87]: [MyThing(1) for _ in range(3)]                                         
Out[87]: [MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING]
In [88]: np.array(_)                                                            
Out[88]: 
array([[[MYTHING, 0]],

       [[MYTHING, 0]],

       [[MYTHING, 0]]], dtype=object)
In [89]: [MyThing(i) for i in range(3)]      # different MyThing parameter each time                                   
Out[89]: [MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING]
In [90]: np.array(_)                                                            
Out[90]: array([MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING], dtype=object)
```

but `np.array([MyThing(2),MyThing(3)])` causes some sort of infinite loop.

---

But back to the issue of `append`.  Normally when building arrays iteratively we recommend collecting values in an list (`list append` is quite fast), and doing one array construction at the end (with `np.array`, `np.stack` and/or `np.concatenate`).

Doing a concatenate iteratively is not recommended.  It is slower, and there are problems creating a valid starting 'empty' array.  Your `x` looks like one such empty starter.  `np.append` gives a false sense that this iteative array construction is as good as the list append approach.  It isn't.  That's part of why I don't like `np.append`.  With `concatenate` you have to at least address the differences in array dimensions directly.  And `concatenate` takes a list, not just two arguments.  So it works outside the loop.

---

With `len` and `iter`, `ThirdPartyThing` (and by inheritance `MyThing`) is an iterable.  `np.array` when constructing an array from a list of these things, tries to iterate on them as well (same as it would with a list of lists).

Instead of making the array from a list of `MyThing`s, I could make an empty object array, and fill it individually.  Now I get a 'clean' array of these objects:

```
In [93]: temp = np.empty(5, object)                                             
In [94]: temp                                                                   
Out[94]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [95]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     temp[i] = MyThing(1) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [96]: temp                                                                   
Out[96]: array([MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, None, None], dtype=object)
```

or even

```
In [100]: temp[:] = [MyThing(1) for _ in range(5)]                              
In [101]: temp                                                                  
Out[101]: array([MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING], dtype=object)
```

Just don't give the list to `np.array`!

This `temp` can be concatenated in various ways:

```
In [102]: np.concatenate([temp,temp,temp])                                      
Out[102]: 
array([MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING,
       MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING,
       MYTHING], dtype=object)
In [103]: np.vstack([temp,temp,temp])                                           
Out[103]: 
array([[MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING],
       [MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING],
       [MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING]], dtype=object)
In [105]: np.append(x,temp)                                                     
Out[105]: array([MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING, MYTHING], dtype=object)
```

Comment: There's a couple of inaccuracies in your answer that I'd like to bring up. I think these are the result of my stating the question poorly so I'm sorry for that. First of all, `MyThing` inherits from `ThirdPartyThing`. Second, it would seem that the flattening issue is a direct result of `ThirdPartyThing` having overloaded `__len__`, which I didn't notice on my first pass-through of the code. Adding `__len__` in, the results I observed manifest.

Comment: Ok, with your code changes, I get similar results.  `temp` as an array is shape (3,1,2).  It can't be concatenated with a (0,) shape array without some sort of dimension tweaking.

Comment: There's definitely something weird about the ThirdPartyThing constructor.  I get different arrays based on whether the parameter is the same or different. And there seems to be some sort of memory,  In any case this is a problem with your class, not with array `append` and/or `concatenate`.

Comment: I agree that `ThirdPartyThing` has a strange implementation; it's not my code. Unfortunately, I don't really have a choice about using this codebase so I have to work around their design decisions

Comment: Making an array from that class is tricky because it's an iterable.  I've demoed an alternative way of constructing an array from your class.

Comment: I can see how that would work. It looks like a huuuuuge pain but it works. Thank you